# How to include multiple td into the tr?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I just wanted to append `td` in the `tr`

**Table**

```
<table class="u-full-width" id="result">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Project Name</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Event</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dave Gamache</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
// Receive Message 
socket.on('message', function(data){
  console.log(data);
  var Project = data.project;
  var Id = data.id;
  var Event = data.event;

  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  var td2 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  var td3 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

  td1.innerHTML = Project;
  td2.innerHTML = Id;
  td3.innerHTML = Event;

  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(td1, td2, td3);
});
```

I come up with this above code but this is not working means see the image...

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The last line is wrong. You should append the `tr` to the table, not all the `td`s.

```
document.getElementById("result").appendChild(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("result").appendChild(td1, td2, td3);

seems you are appending your tds directly to the table, not a tr in the tbody.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to bind your data

```
<table class="u-full-width" id="result">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Project Name</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Event</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bodytable">     
  </tbody>
</table>



    socket.on('message', function(data){
      console.log(data); 
      var _html='';
      html +='<tr>'
      html +='<td>'+data.project+'</td>';
      html +='<td>'+data.id+'</td>';
      html +='<td>'+data.event+'</td></tr>';   
      $('#bodytable').append(_html);
      });
```